# How to add flags to regular expression pattern tests?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, utf-8, mysql-5.7

How to add flags to regular expression pattern tests in MySQL?

Seemingly the pattern isn't case insensitive for some unicode characters as in:

```
SELECT
  UPPER('ö') REGEXP 'Ö' TrueResult,
  'ö' REGEXP 'Ö' FalseResult
;
```

Returns:

```
TrueResult  FalseResult
    1           0
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT
  UPPER('o') REGEXP 'O' TrueResult,
  'o' REGEXP 'O' FalseResult
;
```

returns:

```
TrueResult  FalseResult
    1           1
```

So for example, how to write the equivalent of:

```
SELECT UPPER('ö') REGEXP 'Ö';
```

with regexp flags instead?

Comment: It seems these chars are treated as binary data and are thus case sensitive. Then, all you may do is to use `[Öö]` as regex

Answer (score 1):

`REGEXP` (`RLIKE`), before MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.0 does not handle UTF-8 characters.  It dumbly looks at `Ö` as the two bytes (hex) `C3` and `96`.

Regexps with accented (etc) letters sometimes works, but it more of a coincidence.  Don't trust it.

With `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` datatypes, together with `=`, `LIKE`, etc, and `COLLATION` you can usually get what you need.

If the column containing `Ö` is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`) with *most* `COLLATIONs` other than `utf8_bin`, the "CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS" `Ö` will compare equal at least all of these:

```
O=o=º=Ò=Õ=ò=õ=Ō=ō=Ŏ=ŏ
```

For `utf8_hungarian_ci`, and `utf8_turkish_ci`, `Ö=ö`, but they are treated as a different letter, sorting after `O` and before `P`.

For utf8_danish_ci, utf8_icelandic_ci, and utf8_swedish_ci `Ö=ö`, but they are treated as a different letter, coming after `Z`.

See also [*collation details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html)

In almost all cases, `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` should be avoided in preference to letting the "collation" do the job.

Another note:  Any collation name ending with `_ci` means both "case insensitive" and "accent insensitive".

As for the question "how to write the equivalent of: `SELECT UPPER('ö') REGEXP 'Ö';`, I say:

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'ö' = 'Ö';
+-------------+
| 'ö' = 'Ö'   |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `SET NAMES` is merely to point out that I am using `CHARACTER SET utf8` with its default `COLLATION`, which happens to be `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

***Binary Collation*** might be used :

```
set @letter:='Ö';

select 'ö' like binary @letter FalseResult, 
       'Ö' like binary @letter TrueResult;

FalseResult TrueResult
----------- ----------
    0           1
```